# Byte array display in Firefox

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am hitting a web service which is returning a PDF response. The display is different in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

The display is correct in IE and Chrome, but Firefox doesn't return the correct byte array when displayed.

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0L);
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + title);
response.setContentType(mediaType);
response.setContentLength(bArray.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(bArray);
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

Do I need to set a specific encoding to display it correctly in Firefox too?

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

check out this. maybe you can find a solution